# gnus: nnmaildir (maildir) with with subfolders tree

Tags: emacs, emacs24, gnus

I have configured gnus to use `nnmaildir` with `~/Maildir` directory. Gnus sees/lists maildirs in direct sub-folders (e.g. `~/Maildir/archvives/`) but it does not see/lists maildirs in deeper subfolders e.g. (`~/Maildir/archives/2015/`).

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have configured nnmaildir to use ~/Mail directory.  I have created softlinks in the `~/Mail` directory to selected maildir folders in `~/Maildir` (tree of maildir directories)'
e.g. `~/Mail/XX-YY` -> `~/Maildir/XX/YY`

```
'(gnus-secondary-select-methods
   (quote
    ((nnmaildir "" (directory "~/Mail")))))
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Maildir.html

> Virtual server settings:
>   **directory**
>       For each of your nnmaildir servers (it’s very unlikely that you’d need more than one), you need to create a directory and populate it with maildirs or symlinks to maildirs [...]